# Center div even if it's too wide for the screen

Tags: css

On my login page I have a styled contained with some content inside, with some padding between the two. It looks perfect until the screen width hits the width of the container. Instead of remaining centered on the page, it starts to cut off the right side.

I want it instead of remain centered and cut off equal amounts from the left and right sides. How can I accomplish this?

I've tried all manner of margins and centering techniques but have been unable to accomplish.

**Update**

All of the working solutions I've found online require the parent element to be position:absolute, which due to other restrictions I am unable to use.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by putting equal negative margins onto the entire page

```
margin-left: -10em;
margin-right: -10em;
```

Comment: You can use -100% instead for the same effect (and less reliance on specific units).

Comment: Use % much more predictable behaviour.

Comment: @Creaven ,imsky ... Why is using % more reliable/predictable? I've changed it per your recommendations but the behavior is identical to using em

Answer (score 0):

With different size screens 300px is 300px. If you use 33.3% it will always be a third. The negative is if you go to huge screens where pictures can get stretched etc. there you should start looking at targeting screen sizes etc like bootstrap does out the box.

Update.

Reliable not the best word to use. All are reliable and behave as expected but % will keep your structure better at different screen sizes